# BigQuery - how to compare a "date" column (using legacy SQL)?

Tags: google-bigquery, google-cloud-platform

I have a BigQuery table with a column `Date` which is a `date` type. I am trying to run this query:

```
SELECT * FROM dataset.table_name WHERE Date = "2016-07-11"
```

This throws the error:

```
Argument type mismatch in function EQUAL: 'Date' is type int32, '2016-07-11' is type string
```

I have also tried this query:

```
SELECT * FROM dataset.table_name WHERE Date = TIMESTAMP("2016-07-11")
```

but this returns 0 results, although my table contains at least one record with this value (`2016-07-11`) in the `Date` column.

So, how can I compare a `date` field in BigQuery?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Try below

```
WHERE DATE(Date) = "2016-07-11"
```

My additional recommendation would be to not to use reserved words as column's name, I think if your column was named properly - your original `WHERE` clause would worked perfectly and you would not need to use workaround with `DATE()=""`

Comment: This works, thank you :) I have also managed to make it work using `WHERE CAST(Date as STRING) = "2016-07-11"`. I tried with a different column name, but the original query still threw the _argument type mismatch_ error.

Comment: Accepted you answer. Thank you :)

Comment: Thanks for the solution. FWIW, `DATE` is not listed in [the list of reserved words](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/lexical#reserved_keywords). And changing the column name didn't seem to change the error. The odd thing is that the schema shows the column type is `DATE`.

Comment: @jwadsack - note: this post was for BigQuery Legacy SQL whereas you referencing Standard SQL. Still - consider voting up answer if you liked it :o)

Comment: @MikhailBerlyant just realized that. :) Upvoted because it works for Legacy.  Why the BigQuery web UI defaults to Legacy and hides the checkbox to change that, I don't know.

Comment: consider using BQ Mate (I am author of it) - it has this (nd many other things) addressed - https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/bigquery-mate/nepgdloeceldecnoaaegljlichnfognh

Answer (score 2):

This solution wasn't working for me:

```
DATE(Date) = "2016-07-11"
```

Instead, I had to use:

```
Date = TIMESTAMP("2016-07-11")
```

Comment: It just means that your field is not of date type as in question but rather timestamp!

Comment: I have a timestamp field with example content “2023-06-01T22:10:10 344 UTC . I just want the query to get all the rows matching 2023-06-01 …but it doesnt match unless im querying the whole timestamp string as a exact match … lets say i dont care about the time part and just want all the items matching 2023-06-01