# Get previous distinct number

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I've got the following table:

```
    id         date           status
    1        2017-04-20        good
    1        2017-04-19        bad
    1        2017-04-18        bad
    2        2017-04-20        ok
    2        2017-04-19        ok
    2        2017-04-17        ok
    2        2017-04-16        bad
```

What I need is to get the previous distinct value in **status** column per id.

Assuming that today is 2017-04-20, the result would look like this:

```
        id       previous_status
        1         bad
        2         bad
```

Afterwards, I wanna use this information in the case statement: 
Case when status = 'good' and previous_status = 'bad', ....

Comment: Do you require another column in out put as Status ?

Comment: Doesn't really matter

Comment: Is this related to your previous (deleted) question about state? I have a mostly working query for that if it would still be useful. Let me know!

Answer (score 0):

You could you this for your first requirement:

```
SELECT id, status AS previous_status
FROM table_name
WHERE (id, date_col) IN (
        SELECT id, MAX(date_col)
        FROM table_name
        WHERE DATE(date_col) < "2017-04-20"
    );
```

And this is for second requirement using CASE statement

```
SELECT t.id, t.status, t1.previous_status,
    CASE 
        WHEN t.status = 'good' AND t1.previous_status = 'bad' THEN 'some_value' 
        ELSE 'other_value' 
    END AS case_col
FROM table_name t
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT id, status AS previous_status
    FROM table_name
    WHERE (id, date_col) IN (
            SELECT id, MAX(date_col)
            FROM table_name
            WHERE DATE(date_col) < "2017-04-20"
        )
) t1
ON t.id = t1.id
WHERE DATE(t.date_col) = "2017-04-20";
```

This refer [how_to_compare_date_google_big_query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39075919/bigquery-how-to-compare-a-date-column-using-legacy-sql)